# Swift Create Json for API REST

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, rest

I need create a json for send from a API REST:

```
{
  "ownId": "seu_identificador_proprio",
  "amount": {
    "currency": "BRL",
    "subtotals": {
      "shipping": 1000
    }
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "product": "Descrição do pedido",
      "quantity": 1,
      "detail": "Mais info...",
      "price": 1000
    }
  ],
  "customer": {
    "ownId": "seu_identificador_proprio_de_cliente",
    "fullname": "Jose Silva",
    "email": "nome@email.com",
    "birthDate": "1988-12-30",
    "taxDocument": {
      "type": "CPF",
      "number": "22222222222"
    },
    "phone": {
      "countryCode": "55",
      "areaCode": "11",
      "number": "66778899"
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
      "street": "Avenida Faria Lima",
      "streetNumber": 2927,
      "complement": 8,
      "district": "Itaim",
      "city": "Sao Paulo",
      "state": "SP",
      "country": "BRA",
      "zipCode": "01234000"
    }
  }
}
```

I am confused with the creation..

I try begin with `[NSObject:AnyObject]`

```
    var d1 : [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["ownId":"seu_identificador_proprio", "customer":""]
    let dd1 = ["currency":"BRL"]
    let dd2 = ["shipping":"1000"]
    let arr = [d1]
    let d = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    let s = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    print(s)
```

But I need help!

Comment: are you using swift 3?

Comment: No, swift 2.3 @dirtydanee

Comment: So what's your question? What's wrong with the code you posted? (BTW, there's no reason other than testing to convert your JSON output from NSData to a string, and also no reason to use pretty printing format. For sending to a RESTful server you should not use the pretty format.)

Comment: Your code looks good to me, what is the output for your print(s) ?

Comment: Look good to me. Also you can check [SwiftyJSON too.](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: My dificult is create entries inside other entris, for example: "amount": {
    "currency": "BRL",
    "subtotals": {
      "shipping": 1000
    }
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and added some hints, how can you build the above listed structure. Happy coding!

```
 // Do not use NSObject as key's type
 // Keys in a dictionary are usually Strig in every language
 var d1: [String: AnyObject] = ["ownId":"seu_identificador_proprio", "customer":""]

 // Define the type of your dictionaries, if you dont, in this case it will create a [String:String] dictionary, but you need to insert an array into it
 // Make it a var, so you can mutate the container
 var dd1: [String: AnyObject] = ["currency":"BRL"]
// Here the type is undefined. Try inserting anything else than String, and see the results
let dd2 = ["shipping":"1000"]
dd1["subtotals"] = dd2
d1["amount"] = dd1
// Build all your dictionaries like i did above, and at the end add all of them into arr
let arr = [d1]   
// Do not force try any throwing function in swift - if there is an error, your application will crash
// Use proper error handling - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

do {
 let d = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
 let s = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
 print(s)
} catch {
// Do your error handling here
}
```

Comment: I understand your code, now I will custom for my app, thanks brow, if I have other ask, I post here!

Comment: do not post it here! I am not sure, how will i have time. However, the community is huge, and i am sure somebody will pick up your question.